# ruby gem flickr-fu license problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, flickr

I've trying to get the flickr-fu gem to search correctly only for commercial friendly photos but with no luck.  It seems to ignore the parameter altogether.

```
photos = flickr.photos.search(:text => "anything", 
                              :tags => 'architecture', 
                              #:license_id => '4,6,5', 
                              :license_id => [0,4,5,6],
                              #:license_id => 0,
                              :content_type => '1', 
                              :safe_search => '1', 
                              :sort => 'date-posted-asc, relevance',
                              :per_page => 5)
```

The license IDs 1,2,3 are NonCommercial, so I'm trying to avoid those and take all others, but it doesn't seem to matter, i'm still getting a lot of 3s in my query.

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo.html

http://github.com/commonthread/flickr_fu/blob/master/lib/flickr/photos.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, this seems to work.

```
photos = flickr.photos.search(:text => "anything", 
                              :tags => 'architecture', 
                              :license => '0,4,5,6',
                              :content_type => '1', 
                              :safe_search => '1', 
                              :sort => 'date-posted-asc, relevance',
                              :per_page => 5)
```